# "Cannot call 'ta.rsi' with argument 'length'='lowers'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected"

Tags: indicator, tradingview-api, rsi

**I'm getting this error in pine script**
**could someone help me to solve this code please**
**Here is my code**

Cannot call 'ta.rsi' with argument 'length'='lowers'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected

```
source =(high + low + close)/3
length = input.int(14, minval=1) 
Highlight=input.bool(true, title="Highlight Oversold and Overbought")
uppers = math.sum(volume * (ta.change(source) <= 0 ? 0 : source), length)
lowers = math.sum(volume * (ta.change(source) >= 0 ? 0 : source), length)
mfi = ta.rsi(uppers, lowers)
mfp = plot(mfi, color=color.gray, linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `mfi = ta.rsi(uppers, lowers)` with `mfi = 100.0 - (100.0 / (1.0 + uppers / lowers))` to get the calculation that you intend to; `ta.rsi()` can no longer be used to calculate mfi like that. You can read more about this behavior [in the migration guide](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#removed-an-rsi-overload).